# Vue - TextArea maxLength restriction inconsistent between OS

Tags: html, typescript, vuejs2

I have a textarea input that I'm looking to restrict to a certain number of characters.

```
<textarea
    id="text-area"
    class="form-control"
    v-model="textContent"
    maxlength="100">
</textarea>
<span>{{textContent.length}} / 100</span>
```

This works fine on a windows machine but if it is being interacted with on macOS/iOS using chrome the inconsistency with newline characters causes the textContent.length to never reach the 500 limit as it appears the textarea counts newline characters as 2 characters but the browser does not and will only register 1 character with regards to the binded property's length.

Is there a way to get consistent behavior across the experiences?

Comment: Probably has something to do with `lf`/`crlf` line endings, use `s.replaceAll(/\r\n/g, '\n')` to get rid of `cr` or opposite to add them back

Comment: This doesn't seem to remedy the problem for whatever reason. The input limit still hits before the binded properties length hits the maximum if there are new lines in the text. It's almost like there's a separate internal property to the textArea that I can't modify.